# Swift: NSDictionary as NSArray

Tags: json, swift

```
let voicemailFiles = voicemail.value( forKey: "voicemail") as! [AnyObject]            
// Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10ca8a228) to 'NSArray' (0x10ca89d78)


let voicemailFiles = voicemail.value( forKey: "voicemail") as! [String : String]
// Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x104df9448) to 'NSDictionary' (0x104df7fa8).
```

When trying to put the JSON ( as seen below) into a variable, i am hitting the above errors for the 2 methods of casting for `"voicemail"`.

```
let config = voicemail.value(forKey: "config") as AnyObject
```

This line for the key of config works perfectly.

The variable of `voicemail` is an `[AnyObject]` value of the key, `voicemailboxes`

```
{
  "voicemailboxes": [
    {
      "config": {
        "id": "5",
        "description": "Test"
      },
      "voicemail": [
        {
          "id": "id001",
          "caller": "...",
          "caller_UK": "...",
          "called": "+...",
          "called_UK": "...",
          "received": "...",
          "duration_seconds": "..."
        },
        {
          "id": "id002",
          "caller": "...",
          "caller_UK": "...",
          "called": "..."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand  what is actual issue

Comment: voicemailboxes is `[[string:Any]]` (Array of Dictionary) and  you can access  voicemail which is `[[String:String]]` (Array of dictionary ) by some index

Comment: Like `((dictMain["voicemailboxes"] as! [[String:Any]]).first!["voicemail"] as! [[String:Any]])`

Comment: get value for key 'voicemailboxes' and then store in Array,

Comment: @JonSnow if you'd like to put your comment into an answer, i would be happy to award you the answer. The problem was partly down to different array types of "voicemail" which i wasn't aware of

Comment: @Simon. Glad it works , Added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your JSON it is clear that

`voicemailboxes`  is `[[string:Any]]` **(Array of Dictionary)** and

`voicemail` is  `[[String:String]]` **(Array of Dictionary)**

**NOTE**: `guard` or `if let` required  to check correct response below is just example

You can access it like

`((dictMain["voicemailboxes"] as! [[String:Any]]).first!["voicemail"] as! [[String:Any]])`

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

voicemailboxes is an array of Dictionary.
voicemail is also an array of Dictionary.

Need to parse them appropriately.
On playground:

```
let json = """
{
"voicemailboxes": [
{
"config": {
"id": "5",
"description": "Test"
},
"voicemail": [
{
"id": "id001",
"caller": "...",
"caller_UK": "...",
"called": "+...",
"called_UK": "...",
"received": "...",
"duration_seconds": "..."
},
{
"id": "id002",
"caller": "...",
"caller_UK": "...",
"called": "..."
}
]
}
]
}
"""
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
let voicemailboxes = jsonDict["voicemailboxes"] as! [Any]
let voicemailboxesfirst = voicemailboxes.first as! [String:Any]
let voicemail = voicemailboxesfirst["voicemail"] as! [Any]
let voicemailfirst = voicemail.first as! [String:Any]
print(voicemailfirst)
```

**Output:**

["received": ..., "called": +..., "id": id001, "caller_UK": ..., "duration_seconds": ..., "caller": ..., "called_UK": ...]

Answer (score -2):

use below code

```
if let any = voicemail.value( forKey: "voicemail") {
            if let tmpArray = any as? Array {
                let voicemailFiles = tmpArray
            }
}
```